Pass ReadableStream to <video> while fetch()
I am currently working on embedding videos in our React frontend. The video files (.mp4) are fetched from the .NET backend.
This works relatively well at the moment. The problem is that for large files (150MB) the fetch() takes about ~10sec, which is not a good user experience.
Is it possible to allow the video to play during fetch() before the entire .mp4 file is there and to finish fetching the video in the background?
My approach was to build a ReadableStream, but I don't know how to pass this stream to the ?
Code:
      let fetchResultNeu = await fetch(`${url}/odata/Content/GetFileFromPath`, {
      headers: { ...headers, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(props.content.Path),
    })
    .then((response) => response.body)
    .then((rb) => {
      const reader = rb!.getReader();
      console.log("START STREAM...");
      return new ReadableStream({
        start(controller) {
          // The following function handles each data chunk
          function push() {
            // "done" is a Boolean and value a "Uint8Array"
            reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
              // If there is no more data to read
              if (done) {
                console.log("done", done);
                controller.close();
                return;
              }
              // Get the data and send it to the browser via the controller
              controller.enqueue(value);
              // Check chunks by logging to the console
              console.log(done, value);
              push();
            });
          }
          push();
        },
      });
    })


Does this answer your question? Chrome: to play a video that is being downloaded via fetch/XHR

Hello Konrad, that didn't work for me. Have you some other ideas?
